# Custom classes in message files

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-hydro, serialization, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to communicate (mulitple) custom C++ classes between nodes. On the ROS wiki I have found how to adapt C++ types to be used with publish and subcribe:
http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes

Using the approach above I can publish only one class for each topic.

However, I would also like to use these C++ classes in the messages used by the SimpleActionServer/SimpleActionClient and send some additional information (so not only sending the class itself). Hence, I had to idea to use these classes inside a message file.

I have tried to use a test class in an example message *item_test.msg* with some class *Item*, adapted as described on the ROS wiki.

```
Item item
```

This was to test if it is possible to use the adapted C++ classes with .msg/.srv/.action files. However, I got the following error when compiling:

```
CMake Error at /home/mathijs/git/rose2_0/gui/build/gui_item_selector/cmake/gui_item_selector-genmsg.cmake:3 (message):
Could not find messages which
'/home/mathijs/git/rose2_0/gui/src/gui_item_selector/msg/item_test.msg'
depends on.  Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?

Cannot locate message [Item]: unknown package [custom_classes] on search
path [{{'geometry_msgs':
['/opt/ros/hydro/share/geometry_msgs/cmake/../msg'], 'gui_item_selector':
['/home/mathijs/git/rose2_0/gui/src/gui_item_selector/msg',
'/home/mathijs/git/rose2_0/gui/devel/share/gui_item_selector/msg'],
'std_msgs': ['/opt/ros/hydro/share/std_msgs/cmake/../msg'],
'actionlib_msgs': ['/opt/ros/hydro/share/actionlib_msgs/cmake/../msg'],}}]
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/hydro/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:303 (include)
gui_item_selector/CMakeLists.txt:39 (generate_messages)
```

I have specified generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES custom_classes) in the CMakelist, so that is not the fault.
Is there a way to use the Item class in a .msg/.srv/.action file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129286/custom-classes-in-message-files/) by [mathijsdelangen](https://answers.ros.org/users/11976/mathijsdelangen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-02-14

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-14**:
Is Item a ROS message?

**Comment by [mathijsdelangen](https://answers.ros.org/users/11976/mathijsdelangen/) on 2014-02-15**:
Item is a C++ class which I have adapted for serialization (from http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes)

**Comment by [Okke](https://answers.ros.org/users/7721/okke/) on 2014-02-17**:
I am also looking for a method to uses custom classes as messages in pub/sub, services and GFR. I am building a datamanager node which retrieves data from disk or database and wraps this in an object, which I want to send to another node.

**Comment by [Matias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11721/matias/) on 2014-10-21**:
I'm also looking for an answer to this.

**Comment by [mathijsdelangen](https://answers.ros.org/users/11976/mathijsdelangen/) on 2014-10-22**:
For now, we have still have not found a solution for this. What we do at this moment is using the adaptions of C++ types as described above and sending only one class over topics and services. A big drawback for us is that you lose the interface to Python and introspection of topics/services.

**Comment by [Matias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11721/matias/) on 2014-10-22**:
I just want to clear up that my problem was with services using adapted C++ types, not the multiple-class per-topic problem. In fact, I believe this is a limitation of ROS itself, where you publish one message type per topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is sort of a simple rule to keep in mind when thinking about publish/subscribe custom class, you must always have a defined `.msg` for each topic.

In you original question you mentioned that you have a message `item_test.msg` defined as:

```
Item item
```

Where `Item` is only otherwise defined as a C++ class. This will not work, you must have a corresponding `.msg` definition of the `Item` class. This will generate C++ and Python (others) code for the `Item.msg` message definition, but in your code you can use your own `Item` class and then use the message traits to have a custom serialization for your custom implementation of the `Item` class.

For instance, you might define the `Item.msg` file as:

```
string name
uint32 id
```

This will produce some C++ code like this (simplified):

```
namespace your_package_name {
struct Item_
{
    std::string name;
    uint32_t id;
};
typedef Item_ Item;
}
```

But then you could make your own `Item` class:

```
namespace my_item_class {
class Item {
  public:
    void setName(std::string name) {name_ = name;}
    std::string getName() {return name_;}
    void setId(size_t id) {id_ = id;}
    size_t getId() {return id_;}
  private:
    std::string name_;
    size_t id;
};
}
```

Then you could write the necessary message traits to allow you to publish and subscribe to topics using your custom type (this is an "all-in-one" version):

```
namespace ros
{
namespace message_traits
{
template<> struct IsFixedSize<my_item_class::Item> : public TrueType {};
template<> struct IsSimple<my_item_class::Item> : public TrueType {};

template<>
struct MD5Sum<my_item_class::Item>
{
  static const char* value()
  {
    return MD5Sum<your_package_name::Item>::value();
  }

  static const char* value(const my_item_class::Item& m)
  {
    return MD5Sum<your_package_name::Item>::value(m);
  }
};

template<>
struct DataType<my_item_class::Item>
{
  static const char* value()
  {
    return DataType<your_package_name::Item>::value();
  }

  static const char* value(const my_item_class::Item& m)
  {
    return DataType<your_package_name::Item>::value(m);
  }
};

template<>
struct Definition<my_item_class::Item>
{
  static const char* value()
  {
    return Definition<your_package_name::Item>::value();
  }

  static const char* value(const my_item_class::Item& m)
  {
    return Definition<your_package_name::Item>::value(m);
  }
};
} // namespace message_traits

namespace serialization
{
template<>
struct Serializer<my_item_class::Item>
{
  template<typename Stream, typename T>
  inline static void allInOne(Stream& stream, T item)
  {
    stream.next(item.getName());
    uint32_t id = static_cast<uint32_t>(item.getId());
    stream.next(id);
  }

  ROS_DECLARE_ALLINONE_SERIALIZER;
};
} // namespace serialization
} // namespace ros
```

The majority of the above code is just associating your custom class, `my_item_class::Item`, with the generated, `my_package_name::Item`, message class. This association allows you to use the types interchangeably in your code, but tools and other nodes will always interpret it as a `my_package_name::Item` unless they use the same message trait code above to receive it as the custom class too.

Again the thing to remember is that in order to send something over a topic in ROS you need to have a fully defined message (`.msg` file) with which to associate your custom class.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2016-03-29**:
I don't understand how a ROS message can be associated with a custom c++ class. To begin with, ROS messages don't contain methods.. just fields.... or can they only be associated  with custom c++ classes which don't contain methods?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-29**:
The C++ class generated from `.msg` files cannot be extended, but you can create a custom class which is a superset of the generated class that has additional data and methods and use it as if it were the generated class so long as you define functions to serialize and deserialize them. As above.

**Comment by [NINMort](https://answers.ros.org/users/51359/ninmort/) on 2020-01-31**:
Hello, I tried your example William, I only changed "size_t id;" to "size_t id_;" but when I try to compile I get the following error: "error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::message_traits::MD5Sumgeometry2d::Item_<std::allocator<void > >::value(const my_item_class::Item&)’" with a note saying "note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const my_item_class::Item’ to ‘const geometry2d::Item_std::allocator<void >&’"
What should I be doing different? Full error log here: https://pastebin.com/iTC7ZQ0U

**Comment by [Brent](https://answers.ros.org/users/53657/brent/) on 2020-04-16**:
NINMort, I think the solution is to remove the "m" variable from the three return lines, so:

```
return MD5Sum<your_package_name::Item>::value(m);
```

becomes

```
return MD5Sum<your_package_name::Item>::value();
```

and so on.

It compiles and works for me. I think it makes sense that the purpose of those methods is to return the values of the ROS message type, but it's kind of a guess.